# Is it possible to use PolarPlot together with RegionPlot?

Tags: graphics, numerical-integration

I'm studying a bit about dual integrals by watching this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/2nFRQnmgS48).

I was able to plot two polar functions together:

```
r1=Sqrt[18];R2=6Cos[θ];
g1=PolarPlot[r1,{θ,0,2π}];
g2=PolarPlot[r2,{θ,0,2π}];
Show[{g1,g2}]
```

[image: Image1]

I defined the analysis regions using the RegionPlot function:

```
RegionPlot[x^2+y^2<18,{x,0,10},{y,0,10},PlotStyle->Yellow]
RegionPlot[(x-3)^2+y^2<9,{x,0,10},{y,0,10},PlotStyle->Blue]
RegionPlot[x^2+y^2<18&&(x-3)^2+y^2<9,{x,0,10},{y,0,10}]
```

[image: Image2]

Using the ImplicitRegion function, you get the intersection between these two graphs:

```
ℛ=ImplicitRegion[x^2+y^2<18&&(x-3)^2+y^2<9,{x,y}];
RegionDimension[ℛ]
```

> $ 2 $

The question is as follows:

**Is it possible to use the PolarPlot function within the RegionPlot function?**

I tried something like this, but it was not possible ...

```
RegionPlot[PolarPlot[r1,{θ,0,2π}]&&PolarPlot[r2,{θ,0,2π},{x,{Y,0,10}]
```

I only got by the definition of the circle equation ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear why you want to use [`PolarPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolarPlot.html) within [`RegionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html)

```
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 18, {x, y}];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[(x - 3)^2 + y^2 < 9, {x, y}];
reg3 = RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2];

RegionPlot[{reg1, reg2, reg3}, AspectRatio -> 2 Sqrt[18]/(Sqrt[18] + 6),
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

However, the colors are changed where there is overlap. This can be corrected by using non-overlapping regions.

```
reg4 = RegionDifference[reg1, reg2];
reg5 = RegionDifference[reg2, reg3];

RegionPlot[{reg4, reg5, reg3}, AspectRatio -> 2 Sqrt[18]/(Sqrt[18] + 6),
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: The PolarPlot function seemed interesting because if I did not know the circle equation and having only the radius it is easier to insert the inputs.